# How to enhance notebook microphone quality? Asus u30jc

Tags: drivers, microphone, laptop

I have an asus u30jc notebook and people hear me very badly when we talk via skype or google talk. I've tried to record sound via standard Windows 7 utility and it records really terrible sound. I tried an external microphone and it works great. I don't know if it is a driver or hardware problem. I have the latest drivers from asus website. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated my notebook BIOS to the latest version from asus website. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: I changed my "Realtek Audio Driver" settings to "Studio Quality" and the quality got reasonably better

Answer (score 1):

If you have latest drivers from productor's website on the software side you should be ok.

Just to give it a last try use a linux (ubuntu's really easy) distribution live cd to do the last quality test and if this fails...

We're facing an hardware problem.

In that case:

a) use your pc warranty
b) buy an external mic
c) change (if you are able to) your internal pc mic to a better one :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just a poor microphone. Built in ones often are - they're typically selected for low cost rather than sound quality, and tend to pick up any noise - drives, fans, typing etc. - coming from the computer. As you've already discovered, using an external microphone - even a fairly basic one - will give you much better quality.

Comment: I do not completely agree: internal mic are not great but in these days - at least in my experience - none is so poor to build a "communication wall" in skype

Answer (score 0):

If the mic is that bad, it is probably faulty. A friend of mine has the same notebook and while the microphone is not great, it does the job for skyping.

Do what Pitto proposed and try it with a Linux live CD. This is a definitive test for software errors. If it is bad in Linux and Windows, it is simply broken and needs to be repaired or replaced.

One more remark though: laptop mics pick up all sorts of vibrations, so typing, running fans (high processor/graphics loads) or a spinning DVD in the drive may introduce a lot of noise. Make sure these are not the reason for your troubles.